# Understanding Registers in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am a little confused regarding the usage of registers internally by OpenCL kernels. I am using -cl-nv-verbose to capture the register usage for my kernel. At the moment, my kernel is recording `ptxas info: Used 4 registers` for some code in the kernel. For the following segment:

```
double a;
a = pow(2.0,2.0)
if (index != 0) {
}
```

the registers used changes `ptxas info: Used 6 registers`. I understand that there is nothing in the if loop. But if I re-structure again as:

```
double a;
if (index != 0) {
    a = pow(2.0,2.0)
}
```

this changes the register usage to `ptxas info: Used 15 registers`. I am not changing the work-group sizes for the kernel. Perhaps the answer lies in looking at the ptx code but I don't understand it (though I can get it if needed). What I am more interested in is why the register usage jumps to twice just by moving a line of code. Any ideas? (index is `private`)

Update: PTX Code [before](http://pastebin.com/tWuN7D8k) and [after](http://pastebin.com/4dyZSNgP)

Update: Kernel Code:

```
__kernel void butterfC( __global double *sI,    
                        __global double *sJ,
                        __global double *sK,
                        const int zR, 
                        const int yR,   
                        const int xR,
                        unsigned int l1,
                        const int dir,
                        unsigned int type   ) 
{
    int idX = get_global_id(0);
    int idY = get_global_id(1);
    int idZ = get_global_id(2);

    int BASE = idZ*xR*yR;
    int STRIDE = 1;

    int powX = pow(4.0f,l1);
    int powXm1 = pow(4.0f,l1-1);

    int yIndex, kIndex;

    switch(type)
    {
        case 1: BASE += idY*xR; 
                yIndex  = idX / powXm1 * powX;
                kIndex  = (idX % powXm1) + yIndex;  
                break;
        case 2: BASE += idX; STRIDE = xR; 
                yIndex  = idY / powXm1 * powX;
                kIndex  = idY % powXm1 + yIndex;
                break;
        case 3: BASE = idY*xR + idX; STRIDE = xR * yR; 
                yIndex  = idZ / powXm1 * powX;
                kIndex  = idZ % powXm1 + yIndex;
                break; 
    }

    double a;   

    //a = pow(2.0,2.0);
    if (kIndex != 0) {
        a = pow(2.0,2.0);
        .... do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: A guess that the compiler compiles the `pow` call to a constant in the first case, but not in the second case. The inline expansion of the `pow` function will consume a considerable number of registers. The only way to tell is to look at the PTX.

Comment: We need to see the PTX file to understand the what happening. Is this ALL the code? How is a set if index == 0 ??  as I suspect  the compiler is using extra registers for branch prediction code.

Comment: I have added the ptx code before and after the change. Tim, index==0 does not make any difference.

Comment: @OmarKhan: that is a lot of PTX. Much more than the code snippet you showed above. Could you make the kernel code available as well?

Comment: Okay, sorry for giving things away in chunks. I have updated the question. The lots of PTX is another beef I have, maybe it is related, maybe it is not. All 800 or so lines of PTX code is ONLY due to the presence of the pow() function in the code. If I keep everything intact and just remove the pow() function (appearing 3 times in my code). The PTX is reduced to only TWO lines, `.reg .s32  %r<13>;` and `ret;`. I have observed that the PTX code for pow() in CUDA is much much smaller than that for OpenCL.